# Select full row using check box in MFC

Tags: mfc

I have list control including check box for each row. I want to select the entair row when selecting the check box. How can I do this ? What is the code sinnipt for that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the dialog (best in `OnInitDialog`) use following code:

```
DWORD dwStyle = m_list.GetExtendedStyle();
dwStyle |= LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT;
m_list.SetExtendedStyle(dwStyle);
```